# Re-request Authorization in WinRT applications

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, authorization, webcam

When using a media capture in winRT from c# code, the user is prompted to allow access to the webcam and microphone. If the user accepts this everything works fine, if the user refuses I will receive an UnauthorizedAccessException and I'll go pack to the previous page.

My question is, when I receive the unauthorized exception, how do i get the user to be prompted again for the access to the webcam and/or audio? Forcing the user to uninstall seems rather un-userfriendly.

I've been trying to find information on google but winRT seems to be rather hard to find decent documentation for.
Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Guidelines for devices that access personal data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh768223.aspx).  In the case of [MediaCapture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.mediacapture.aspx) specifically, if you get the access exception after the user says "no" to the initial prompt you'll want inform the user of that and recommend he/she re-enable access via the Permissions section of the Settings pane.  After the user manually renables, you'll then also need to re-call [InitializeAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br226599.aspx).

In particular check out ["Guidelines for notifying the user of device revocation"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh768223.aspx#guidelinesfornotifying) (which due to formatting doesn't cut and paste well); it gives suggested verbiage for the condition where they have blocked access via the consent prompt or settings versus the device not being present.

Note too that guidance prescribes that you should not programmatically invoke the Permissions page on the Settings charm to prompt them to re-enable.

Comment: Thank you,I was affraid it was going to be something like this, it's still better than having to re-install. I guess it will take some getting used to the new microsoft products.